# Setting the Content-Type of an empty response in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-type

In order to support a legacy application that's in the field, I need my ASP.NET MVC app to return an empty response that also has a `Content-Type`. One of IIS, ASP.NET, or ASP.NET MVC is removing my `Content-Type` when I send back a null response. Is there any way around this?

(While not requiring an empty response with a set `Content-Type` would obviously be the ideal solution, the clients are already out there, and many of them cannot be upgraded.)

**EDIT**: Since there was a request for code: I'm proxying the request from the new web application to the one that older clients rely on. To do this, I have a subclass of `ActionResult`, called `LegacyResult`, that you can simply return for those methods that need to be handled by the old software. This is the relevant part of its code:

```
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        using (var legacyResponse = GetLegacyResponse(context))
        {
            var clientResponse = context.HttpContext.Response;
            clientResponse.Buffer = false;
            clientResponse.ContentType = legacyResponse.ContentType; /* Yes, I checked that legacyResponse.ContentType is never string.IsNullOrEmpty */
            if (legacyResponse.ContentLength >= 0) clientResponse.AddHeader("Content-Length", legacyResponse.ContentLength.ToString());

            var legacyInput = legacyResponse.GetResponseStream();
            using (var clientOutput = clientResponse.OutputStream)
            {
                var rgb = new byte[32768];
                int cb;
                while ((cb = legacyInput.Read(rgb, 0, rgb.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    clientOutput.Write(rgb, 0, cb);
                }
                clientOutput.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

If `legacyInput` has data, then `Content-Type` is set appropriately. Otherwise, it's not. I can actually kluge the old backend to send an empty v. non-empty response for exactly the same request, and observe the difference in Fiddler.

**EDIT 2**: Poking around with Reflector reveals that, if headers have not been written at the time that `HttpResponse.Flush` is called, then `Flush` writes out the headers itself. The problem is that it only writes out a tiny subset of the headers. One of the missing ones is `Content-Type`. So it seems that, if I can force headers out to the stream, I can avoid this problem.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's Flushing the empty stream? What happens if you comment out everything after setting `ContentType`?

Comment: Commenting out everything after the `ContentType` makes no difference; the behavior's the same. This ends up being because `Flush` still gets called, but by elsewhere in the ASP.NET stack. (In other words, it appears that line could be removed with no ill-effects, but doing so doesn't change the behavior, either.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to trick the response into writing the headers, by falsely telling it there's content, then [suppressing it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponsebase.suppresscontent.aspx):

```
/// [inside the writing block]
var didWrite = false;
while ((cb = legacyInput.Read(rgb, 0, rgb.Length)) > 0)
{
  didWrite = true;
  clientOutput.Write(rgb, 0, cb);
}
if (!didWrite)
{
  // The stream needs a non-zero content length to write the correct headers, but...
  clientResponse.AddHeader("Content-Length", "1");
  // ...this actually writes a "Content-Length: 0" header with the other headers.
  clientResponse.SuppressContent = true;
}
```